# how to insert content into wp_head after loop_end

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, hooks

I'm trying to access the info on a post, so I can get the post title and post content so that I can generate the respective OG tags to put in the header.
Problem is that the info is only avaiable after loop_end. How can I go about  inserting into head after that action occurs?

Edit: Here's the code being used

```
<?php
/**
 * *snip*
 * standard plugin info
 * *snip*
 */

$jobTitle ="";
$jobDescription ="";

function getJobInfo() {
    global $jobTitle,$jobDescription;
    if (is_single()) {
        $jobTitle = get_jobs()->get("job_title");
        $jobDescription = get_jobs()->get("job_description");
    }
}

add_action("loop_end", 'getJobInfo'); // the info is only available on this hook since this is part of a plugin that modifies some pages.

function generateOGtag(){
    global $jobTitle,$jobDescription;
    echo "<meta property='og:title' content='$jobTitle'>\n";
    echo "<meta property='og:title' content='$jobDescription'>\n";
}
add_action("wp_head", 'generateOGtag');
```

According to the wordpress plugin reference it does state that `wp_head` is loaded before `loop_end` so, how am I going to get the info from the `loop_end` action into the `wp_head` action?

Comment: Did you write the plugin that creates the `$job*` data?

Comment: Nop, the info is from WpJobBoard, and the $job* on the snippet are created by me.

Comment: I downvoted your question because you have asked this on SO, I have answered it just to be told that your info in your question is incomplete, you deleted it and reasked the same question here **without** the missing info.

Comment: Downvote at will since this was a cross post from stack overflow with 5 minute difference since here its the propper question board to ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the plugin you are using does not provide the data you need until the `loop_end` hook, getting information into the header is going to be tricky. I can only think of two ways to proceed:

1. Use Javascript to insert the data into the header after page load. I
   don't know if this will work. I am not sure if the "og" headers will
   be respected.
2. Run a loop before the page loads, and get your data early. I have no
   to test that but I imagine it too look something like this:

---

```
function generateOGtag(){
  if (is_single()) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (have_posts()) {
      while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        // no idea if your plugin needs anything else here
      }
    }
    $jobTitle = get_jobs()->get("job_title");
    $jobDescription = get_jobs()->get("job_description");
    echo "<meta property='og:title' content='$jobTitle'>\n";
    echo "<meta property='og:title' content='$jobDescription'>\n";
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
}
add_action("wp_head", 'generateOGtag');
```

This is obviously a labor intensive procedure as code will run twice.

Comment: So far I've used a combination of output buffering and db query. Although I don't like the output buffering solution (starting ob on init and flushing on shutdown) it gets the job done, but I'm concerned about some other plugin (in the future) sending some headers or something that "breaks" output buffering, so I'm considering that db query option although the plugin doesn't use anything from the $wp_post but the post slug. Does wp have some kind of db cache to store the query made in the wp_query?